# Run example "eg008_create_template.py"

Tags: python, docusignapi

I am trying to create a DocuSign template using a python app.
To do this, I am exploring the following github repository:
https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python

I am trying to run "eg008_create_template.py", which can be found at code-examples-python/app/eSignature/examples

To execute it, I just go to the correct directory and run the script using:

*python3 eg008_create_template.py*

By doing this, it should then create a template in my developer test account on the demo environment, but it does not.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set all the required configuration (and update the configuration file in your Python code) - IK (client ID) and secret key as well as redirectURI on your developer account.

I highly recommend you try to use [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/) instead as it will do all of this for your automatically.

Comment: Yes, I have used quickstart but the result is the same.

Comment: I have also changed the import "docusign" to "jwt_helper" in the example "eg008_create_template.py" since the file docusign is not found.

Comment: what do you mean "result is the same"? you get an error? what error? can you post a screenshot of your error?

Comment: The thing is that I do not know how to execute the example "eg008_create_template.py". Since this example only contains the class and there is not any other file that executes it.

Comment: Thus, when executing: *python3 eg008_create_template.py* I do not obtain any result.

Comment: Is there a file in the DocuSign repository that calls this example? I have seen that jwt_console.py executes the example "eg002_signing_via_email.py". Is there a file that does the same thing but for the example "eg008_create_template.py"?

Comment: you need to call run.py

Comment: But when running "run.py", the example "eg001_embedded_signing.py" is executed by default. How can I modify the script so that I execute "eg008_create_template.py"?

Comment: Find your configuration file (ds_config.py) and change quickstart=false

Comment: I obtain the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)`

Comment: `File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1519, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()`

Comment: `File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1503, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 509, in <lambda>
    view_func=lambda **kw: self_ref().send_static_file(**kw),  # type: ignore # noqa: B950
 `

Comment: `File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/scaffold.py", line 322, in send_static_file
    return send_from_directory(
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/helpers.py", line 676, in send_from_directory
    return werkzeug.utils.send_from_directory(  # type: ignore
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 71, in __getattr__
    value = getattr(self._real_module, item)`

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'werkzeug.utils' has no attribute 'send_from_directory'`

Comment: You may need to install some packages in order to run the Flask app. You can do that by running `pip install -r requirements.txt` 

It looks like your errors are related to dependencies

Comment: On the other hand, is it normal to obtain the following error when creating a new template?

Comment: * Running on http://localhost:3000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 182-197-937
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:22:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:22:49] "GET /eg008 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:02] "POST /eg008 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2091, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)`

Comment: `File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2076, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1519, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  `

Comment: `File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lluis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/envs/docusign-template-app_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1503, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Lluís/Desktop/Definitiu-python/app/docusign/utils.py", line 55, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
 `

Comment: `File "/mnt/c/Users/Lluís/Desktop/Definitiu-python/app/eSignature/views/eg008_create_template.py", line 30, in create_template
    results = Eg008CreateTemplateController.worker(args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Lluís/Desktop/Definitiu-python/app/eSignature/examples/eg008_create_template.py", line 43, in worker
    results = res.templates[0]
AttributeError: 'TemplateSummary' object has no attribute 'templates'`
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:02] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:03] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:03] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:03] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:03] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jul/2022 10:23:03] "GET /eg008?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: I think that your code has been updated and in the object "res" of the example "eg008_create_template" there is no key called "Templates"

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This was a bug in our code but has been resolved now so if you pull the latest from github it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

To run the Python code in the code-examples-python GitHub repo you first need to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the dependencies of the Flask app. Even when downloading a Quickstart you'll need to run this command.

In the thread above, some of the errors were related to a bug in the code but the fix has been pushed to the repository so if you pull the latest master branch or do a fresh git clone you should be able to run the example.